# CSS - Removing vertical container borders

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out where these 1px borders are being called in the CSS for:

http://ecbiz103.inmotionhosting.com/~jrbald5/

Underneath the post thumbnails on that page are two vertical border lines. When I debug through the Chrome developer tools, and "uncheck" the "clear:both" style in li_container1 div, they go away, but I can't find this anywhere in the actual CSS to edit out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're coming from your `background-image: url("images/main-bg.gif");` declaration in your ".li_container" class definition on line 206.